# Computer freeze into blue blank screen aften 5 mins

Tags: windows-7, freeze, blank-screen

I'm experiencing a wierd problem with this computer. About 5 minutes after booting the machine freezes into a blue blank screen (not BSOD). The screen is completely blank, not even a cursor is visible. After a reboot however the computer works just fine and no more blue screen occurs. The next day the same thing happens, but only on the first boot.

I've testet the RAM with both memtest86+ and the native tester in Windows. Neither found any errors.

So, any suggestions?

Comment: When it freezes, are you still able to open up Task Manager (by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del or Ctrl+Shift+Esc)?

Comment: Don't know. Going to try this on the next occurrence...

Comment: If you can open up Task Manager, go to *File* > *New Task (Run..)* then put in "explorer.exe" (without the quotes). That should bring back the normal desktop as well as the Taskbar and Start menu. You can then begin troubleshooting from there.

Comment: Check your event viewer logs for any logged events that may give clues.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-information-appears-in-event-logs-Event-Viewer

Comment: @Isxek Wouldn't the cursor still be visible if it's only explorer.exe that crashes?

Comment: I'm curious about what the event viewer says as well. Have you tried updating your video card drivers?